# Check Component Dependency magento 2.1.10

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, composer, php-7

I am using Magento 2.1.10. While trying to install an extension. I am getting the following error.
[image]

Also I am using **php version 7.0.6**, but PHP version Check is showing **5.6.25**.
Also earlier I tried to install extension on another machine which passed the test but there was no progress in installing.

How can I solve this issues?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: did you solved your issue?

Comment: No. not solved yet.